# Number of faces visible in different dimensions

Tags: geometry

In 3D, if I look at a cube, at most I can see three faces at one time from any given perspective, e.g. by looking at a corner dead on.

In 2D, if I look at a square and my perspective is in the plane determined by the square, at most I can see two "faces" (lines).

In 1D, if I look at a segment (which is I suppose the notion of a square/cube for 1D), at most I can see one "face" (the segment endpoint).

My question is, how does this concept generalize to an $n$ dimensional hypercube? Does it grow linearly as the pattern suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $n$ dimensions the hypercube will have $2n$ faces with normals in the directions

$$(\pm 1,0,0,0, \ldots ,0),$$
$$(0,\pm 1,0,0, \ldots ,0),$$
$$(0,0,\pm 1,0, \ldots ,0),$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(0,0,0,0, \ldots ,\pm 1)$$

You can only 'see' one of each of the +/- pairs as if one is directed towards the observer the one will be facing away (unless you are inside the hypercube), so *cannot* see more than half the faces.

But an observer at point $(x,x,x,x, \ldots, x)$, with $x > 1/2$, will always be able to see all $n$ of the positive directed faces of a unit hypercube.

So, yes - the number of faces grows linearly, and you can see half of them from the right direction.

Comment: @pjs36 thanks for the edit